# Which is the best way to clean leather shoes?

Tags: cleaning, shoes

Does anybody know the best way way to clean leather shoes without spoiling them?

Comment: As the scope of LH says: lifehack is a technique that can be implemented quickly and is used to make one's physical life more efficient when a more standard approach (as defined by that area's experts) or a product is either unavailable or undesirable. Lifehacks are creative, meaning they use materials that are on hand for uses besides their intended use. I think my question is not off-topic because happens to me that  I spoil my shoes when I try to clean it and I wanted to know a trick or a best way to clean it without spoil it. @Adam Zuckerman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a pumpkin based soap which is very effective with my leather shoes, I usually wax them after the washing procedure. The soap looks kinda like this:

[image]

I believe this soap is from a Mexican brand, but I'm sure you will be able to find something similar if not the same. I doubt it'll be hard to find.

1. Add a couple of drops of water on the paste, so it can become soapy
2. You can use an old toothbrush, and gently get some of the paste on it and start brushing your shoe(it's better if you've dusted off the shoe)
3. Once the shoe has been brushed, with a dry and clean cloth remove the excess of liquid and soap
4. Once it's dry your shoe is ready for waxing.
5. Dispose of any excess water on the paste and let it air-dry before closing it.

Comment: Do not spoils the shoes with water?

Comment: you do have to put a couple of drops of water on the paste for it to be effective otherwise its just dry paste. Once you've brushed the entirety of the shoe, dry it off with a cloth, then proceed to the waxing